# Asp.net Validation message text changing by Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

What i trying to do is.Making a Login Form for users.i using there Asp.net RequiredFieldValidator for Text Box's. I using Jquery to Disable the Cut or Copy event fot those text Box and showing a message to user that "Cut Copy is disabled".I taking a label to show that.but i want to do that by validator control text.i tried to override the CSS for RFV but not the success.How to do that..

and i want to created one function to do rather that writing as many as text box's are the...
 here is what i tried...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#<%=txtUserId.ClientID %>').bind('cut copy paste', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#<%=UserNameDislbl.ClientID %>").text('Cut/Copy  is Disabled for User Id');
            $('#<%=UserNameDislbl.ClientID %>').addClass('flashText');
            $('#<%=UserNameDislbl.ClientID %>').fadeIn(900, function(e) {
                $('#<%=UserNameDislbl.ClientID %>').fadeOut(2200);
            });

        });
```

..
i need to pass the id of text box and corresponding RFV id to show the text..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think this is a bad UI design decision. What if they need an auto-generated password sent to them by email when they forget their password at a future time? In such a scenario most users expect to be able to do this until they can login again and create a new password for themselves.

Comment: I doing this for the Administrator Which is the hard Coded as the requirement